# Unable to output array to a specific format

Tags: php, arrays, yii, chart.js

I am trying to get this array output in this format to be used by Chart.js in Yii.

This is the array I need to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 50
            [color] => rgba(66,66,66,1)
            [label] => Hunde
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 25
            [color] => rgba(66,66,66,1)
            [label] => Katzen
        )
)
```

This is the code that produces the above array:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "value" => 50,
        "color" => "rgba(66,66,66,1)",
        "label" => "Hunde"
    ),
    array(
        "value" => 25,
        "color" => "rgba(66,66,66,1)",
        "label" => "Katzen"
    ),
);
```

This is the code I am typing:

```
protected function modulesArray(){
    $modules = Module::model()->findAll();

    foreach ($modules as $module) {
        $array[] = array("value" => 50, "color" => "$module->color", 
            "label" => "$module->category");

    }
    return $array;  
}
```

And this is the array output I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 50
            [color] => #b83333
            [label] => Tyres
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 50
            [color] => #3276eb
            [label] => Hydraulics
        )    
)
```

The thing is, I don't seem to see any difference except for the color (which is allowed to be put in hex values), however, when I merge my array to the above array, the charts seem to load fine. Does this mean the array output that I get is fine?

I am trying to get my head around it as everything seems fine! I have no clue what am I doing wrong.

P.S : -

This is the widget section code:

```
<?php 
    $this->widget(
        'ext.chartjs.widgets.ChPolar', 
        array(
            'width' => 250,
            'height' => 250,
            'htmlOptions' => array(),
            'drawLabels' => true,
            'datasets' => $modulesArray,
            'options' => array()
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript that handles this? You may need to convert the hex color to RGBa

Comment: I tried added the Hex to rgba as well. But still am not able to get it to work. The array looks perfect. But the example array works and mine does'nt so that means maybe somewhere my array is off?

Comment: Show the javascript code

Comment: Also, how are you outputting this from PHP? In what format? JSON I'd hope.

Comment: I am using the Yii extension for the ChartJs http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-chartjs/

If we use the default array, it is working, however if we use our array, it is not working.

Comment: Can you show how you're combining that generated array with the other properties for Yii?  Paste the entire `$this->widget()` section.

Comment: Added the widget code in the question. Hope that helped?

Comment: What is the array element [value] for?  In the sample one is 25, the other is 50.  Does that mean two different data points?  In your array all are 50.  Does that mean you will only get a single point?